# Set referer of Simple HTML Dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom, http-referer

Can we set the referer (`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`) of Simple HTML Dom?

Something similar to

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_REFERER,"http://google.com");
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: No, but you can download with curl and pass the response to simple.

Comment: @pguardiario how do I pass the html from curl to simple? `$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $html); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);` and then `file_get_html($output)`?

Comment: I believe you want str_get_html()